# Django Edit User profile model

Tags: python, django

The views function send two forms to template and receive data from it, it saves the changes about User (email, first_name, last_name), but don't save for second form

Views:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user_form = form.save()
        custom_form = profile_form.save(False)
        custom_form.user = user_form
        custom_form.save()
        print(custom_form)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
    return render(request, 'root/profile.html', {"client_info": client_info,
                                         "client_details": client_details,
                                         "form_1": EditProfileForm,
                                         "form_2": UserProfileInfoForm})
```

Forms:

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name'
        )

class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ("social_media_ins", "social_media_vk", "social_media_tk",
                  "social_media_fb", "social_media_youtube",)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't added your models, I assume that UserProfileInfo model contains file field one or more. So, to save a file from form you have to add files field in form instance i.e. `profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(request.POST, instance=request.user, files=request.FILES)` and in template add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag. Also make sure you have added media root and media url in settings and added urls in urls.py file. For more info look https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#file-uploads

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in profile form, it supposed to be profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofileinfo)

Comment: @Danil Melnikov Plz always add related models. They might be helpful.